# R maptools wrld_simpl in rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2, r-maptools

In R:

```
import(maptools)
data(wrld_simpl)
```

In python rpy2, how do I access `wrld_simpl`? The following code (in Python) fails as follows...`package "maptools" has no attribute wrld_simpl`

```
maptools = importr('maptools')
data = DataFrame(maptools.wrld_simpl)
```

Just trying to understand rpy2 (and revisit R from university days)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `rpy2.robjects.packages.data`, as demonstrated in the [rpy2 introduction](https://rpy2.github.io/doc/latest/html/introduction.html#graphics-and-plots):

```
>>> from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr, data

>>> maptools = importr('maptools')
>>> spatial_df_r = data(maptools).fetch('wrld_simpl')['wrld_simpl']
>>> spatial_df_r
<rpy2.robjects.methods.RS4 object at 0x7ffa932b0cc0> [RTYPES.S4SXP]
R classes: ('SpatialPolygonsDataFrame',)
```

You also seem to be trying to convert the data to `pandas.DataFrame`. The slight issue is that the data is not a data frame, but a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` object. You can however convert it to a proper `data.frame`:

```
>>> base = importr('base')
>>> df_r = base.as_data_frame(spatial_df_r)
>>> tuple(df_r.rclass)
('data.frame',)
```

and then to pandas DataFrame:

```
from rpy2.robjects import conversion
from rpy2.robjects import default_converter, pandas2ri

with conversion.localconverter(default_converter + pandas2ri.converter):
    df = conversion.rpy2py(df_r)
```

where `df` is now a pandas DataFrame:

```
>>> type(df)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

However, if you are using Jupyter, the conversion can be done much more easily with with `-o` option of rpy2 magic, see: [using rpy2 in notebooks](https://rpy2.github.io/doc/latest/html/generated_rst/notebooks.html) and [rpy2.ipython.rmagic](https://rpy2.github.io/doc/latest/html/interactive.html#module-rpy2.ipython.rmagic).